# Can we use arduino.getKey() for getting Keyboard events?

Tags: arduino, keyboard, emulation

Can we use arduino get key function to know which keys are getting pressed on laptops/desktops across OS's ?

I read its for USB , does this mean it cannot be used for Laptops embedded keyboards.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Arduino GetKey man page](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/GetKey) tells that this function:

> Reports the ASCII value of a key being pressed or released on an attached USB keyboard.

The keyword here is not "USB", but "attached". You need the signals from the keyboard to pass through the arduino itself in order for it to detect the key. Moreover the object controlling it is of type `USBHost`.

Consequently, in order to use this you need an arduino with a USB host interface (Mega ADK for instance), connect the keyboard to its usb interface and then do whatever you want.

As you can see, laptops' keyboards cannot be connected to the usb host port (they are internal) so... No way. But moreover the `getKey` function cannot even read the USB keyboard you have attached to your PC. You need to connect it to the arduino.

In the end, if you want to read the inputs of the keyboard (connected to the PC) you will need to use a program on the PC itself to grab the keyboard input and redirect it to the arduino (maybe through serial?).

Comment: Ahh , okay .. thanks for this clarification , Upvote.